# Keyword highlighting issues in Java (using System.out)

Tags: java, console, system.out

I have been modifying a simple Java Swing console, and I decided to add a form of highlighting for keywords (by coloring the area next to flagged lines). I got it to work fine when I throw errors by searching for the keyword "Exception", but when I do a System.out.println with the keyword in it, it highlights everything. I think the string is somehow being combined with all of the strings already entered, which is the cause for this error, but I am having trouble fixing it.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The text "Hello World 2" and "Lets throw an error on this console" should not be highlighted.

```
// Edited by Jeff B
// A simple Java Console for your application (Swing version)
// Requires Java 1.1.5 or higher
//
// Disclaimer the use of this source is at your own risk. 
//
// Permision to use and distribute into your own applications
//
// RJHM van den Bergh , rvdb@comweb.nl

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class textAreaC extends JTextArea {
    int rowCount;
    int rowHeight;
    ArrayList<Point> exPoint = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public textAreaC() {
        rowHeight = this.getRowHeight();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for (int i = 0; i < exPoint.size(); i++) {
            g.fillRect(3, exPoint.get(i).x * rowHeight, 10, exPoint.get(i).y
                    * rowHeight);
        }
    }

    public void append(String str) {
        int rows = str.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length;
        if (str.contains("Exception")) {
            //System.out.println("This was the string: " + str + "It has " + rows + "rows" + " End String");
            exPoint.add(new Point(rowCount, rows));
        }
        rowCount += rows;
        super.append(str);

    }
}

public class Console extends WindowAdapter implements WindowListener,
        ActionListener, Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;
    private textAreaC textArea;
    private Thread reader;
    private Thread reader2;
    private boolean quit;

    private final PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
    private final PipedInputStream pin2 = new PipedInputStream();

    Thread errorThrower; // just for testing (Throws an Exception at this Console

    public Console() {
        // create all components and add them
        frame = new JFrame("Java Console");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension frameSize = new Dimension((int) (screenSize.width / 2),
                (int) (screenSize.height / 2));
        int x = (int) (frameSize.width / 2);
        int y = (int) (frameSize.height / 2);
        frame.setBounds(x, y, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);

        textArea = new textAreaC();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setMargin(new Insets(3, 20, 3, 3));
        JButton button = new JButton("clear");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textArea),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(this);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        try {
            PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(this.pin);
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(pout, true));
        } catch (java.io.IOException io) {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n"
                    + io.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n"
                    + se.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            PipedOutputStream pout2 = new PipedOutputStream(this.pin2);
            System.setErr(new PrintStream(pout2, true));
        } catch (java.io.IOException io) {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n"
                    + io.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n"
                    + se.getMessage());
        }

        quit = false; // signals the Threads that they should exit

        // Starting two seperate threads to read from the PipedInputStreams             
        //
        reader = new Thread(this);
        reader.setDaemon(true);
        reader.start();
        //
        reader2 = new Thread(this);
        reader2.setDaemon(true);
        reader2.start();

        // testing part
        // you may omit this part for your application
        // 
        //System.out.println("Test me please Exception\n testing 123");
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.println("Hello World 2");

        System.out.println("\nLets throw an error on this console");
        errorThrower = new Thread(this);
        errorThrower.setDaemon(true);
        errorThrower.start();
    }

    public synchronized void windowClosed(WindowEvent evt) {
        quit = true;
        this.notifyAll(); // stop all threads
        try {
            reader.join(1000);
            pin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            reader2.join(1000);
            pin2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public synchronized void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        frame.setVisible(false); // default behaviour of JFrame 
        frame.dispose();
    }

    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        textArea.setText("");
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            while (Thread.currentThread() == reader) {
                try {
                    this.wait(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                if (pin.available() != 0) {
                    String input = this.readLine(pin);
                    textArea.append(input);
                    //System.out.println(input.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length);
                }
                if (quit)
                    return;
            }

            while (Thread.currentThread() == reader2) {
                try {
                    this.wait(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                if (pin2.available() != 0) {
                    String input = this.readLine(pin2);
                    textArea.append(input);
                }
                if (quit)
                    return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            textArea.append("\nConsole reports an Internal error.");
            textArea.append("The error is: " + e);
        }

        // just for testing (Throw a Nullpointer after 1 second)
        if (Thread.currentThread() == errorThrower) {
            try {
                this.wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "Application test: throwing an NullPointerException It should arrive at the console");
        }
    }

    public synchronized String readLine(PipedInputStream in) throws IOException {
        String input = "";
        do {
            int available = in.available();
            if (available == 0)
                break;
            byte b[] = new byte[available];
            in.read(b);
            input = input + new String(b, 0, b.length);
        } while (!input.endsWith("\n") && !input.endsWith("\r\n") && !quit);
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new Console(); // create console with not reference 
    }
}
```

I have been doing a little testing, take a look at this printout:
[image]

To replicate this, add a System.out.prinln statement in reader(1) and append the input to the end of the string. This is what my prinlns look like:

```
System.out.println("There should be a string before me.");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println("Test me please Exception");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println("Test print 2");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println("Test print 3");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println("Test me please Exception 2");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println("Exception here lololol");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println("Hello World 2");
System.out.flush();
```

And my reader one looks like this:

```
if (pin.available()!=0)
    {

        String input=this.readLine(pin);
        System.out.println("this was printed by the thread second " + input);
        textArea.append(input);
        //System.out.println(input.split("\r\n|\r|\n").length);
    }
if (quit) return;
```

It is treating all of those prinlns as a single input, is this something java is doing, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should add screenshots illustrating the undesirable behavior. Most folks won't be willing to run your code just to see what you are describing with words.

Comment: The problem is in how often the append() method is invoked. Multiple System.out.println() invocations are being combined into one call to the append() method. This even happens even when I add a flush() after every call. I'm not sure how to force each println() call to equate to an append() call.

Comment: Another approach can be highlight the text differently depending on whether the output was generated by System.out or System.err. See [MessageConsole](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for this type of approach. I tried using the message console for your current requirement but still had problems. Each println() was recognized correctly, but the output from the Exception was considered 3 lines, not 1. Since each line doesn't contain the word "exception" it was not highlight correctly.

Comment: @camickr Thanks, I would like to get what I have working though, as with that method, you can only sort out two different types of inputs. Using a keyword method, I could have an undefined number of keywords and different highlights for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML for output, that is easier. Just as first text `<html>` would do (very loose HTML).
Or set the content type.
Append lines with `<br>` and so on.

It is more flexible.

---

You did two appends of multiline strings. Taking the number of rows would make all lines in the string red. Maybe this suboptimal version is more like what you intended.

```
@Override
public void append(String str) {
    String[] lines = str.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
    int rows = lines.length;
    for (String line : lines) {
        super.append(line + "\n");
        if (line.contains("Exception")) {
            exPoint.add(new Point(rowCount, 1)); // 1 line
        }
        ++rowCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that requires use of JEditorPane, not JTextArea correct? (I was using JEditorPane before, but was having issues getting it to play nice with multiple threads)

Comment: You are right: JEditorPane or JTextPane. About being careful for multiple threads too. Should be doable though.

Comment: The requirement is paint a bar down the left, not hightlight the text. Working with dynamic HTML is not easier than working with plain text in this case.

Comment: Thanks Joop, if I switch it, just the first line is highlighted, no matter where the "Exception" key word (this is because it treats everything sent through System.out as a single string, but why does it do this?) It seems that anything sent through Exceptions are treated as separate strings. When you say "sub-optimal" what do you mean?

Comment: If the first line highlights, then that should mean, you do not increase rowCount by 1 in the for loop. Suboptimal because now there is line wise appending and Point.y superfluous, just could use integer list.

Comment: The behaviour of System.out might be due to the piped input stream. Not sure.

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks. I have a feeling that it is indeed the piped input stream doing this shenanigans. Thanks for the help!